# Why does passing in an integer that's from a vector not work in make_pair?

Tags: c++, vector, maps

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int solution(vector<int> a) {
    map<int, bool> ints;
    int b;
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        if(ints[a.at(i)]) {
            return i;
        }
        else {
            ints.insert(make_pair((a.at(i)), true));
            cout << a.at(i) << " " << ints[a.at(i)] << endl;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a = {2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2};
    solution(a);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The point is to return the location of the first duplicate, yet the make_pair is never doing its job. I don't know why but it is not working, as you can see by testing the output it is never turning ints[someint] to have a boolean value of true. Yet if I replace a.at(i) with an integer then the output is as expected.
What is going on? Can you not pass a.at(i) as an argument for make_pair??

Comment: std::pair is a semantically meaningless type and is intended to be used in templates (where semantics are not known yet). In all other cases just declare a struct with two members of your own. Passing vectors by value is usually not needed either.  All in all you code looks like you are still learning C++ (and then competitive coding is not a good place to start).

Comment: Better sources to learn C++ from are a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (make sure it is up-to-date and not teaching you "C"). Or you can use  [learncpp.com](https://learncpp.com/). Also make sure to check [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to explore what C++ has to offer (containers/algorithms). 
And finally refer to the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to learn how C++  is intended to be used.

Comment: What is the exact compiler error? I suspect it is warning you about a reference

Comment: @PepijnKramer Apparently the code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/r4j9c5sbq).  To OP see [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: `map::operator[]` does not do what you think it does. It is also a good idea to inspect result of `map::insert`.

Comment: If the key doesn't exist in the map already then `ints[a.at(i)]` inserts the key with a default value of `false` in this case. Then `insert` fails because the key already exists . Use `if(ints.find(a.at(i)) != ints.end())` instead to determine if the key already exists. If all you want to know is if you've seen the number before then you chould use an `unordered_set` or `set` instead.

Comment: The code compiles fine on both the codesignal platform where the problem came from and my local compiler with no warnings. The function parameter was already given it wasn't my choice, CodeSignal chose to not pass by reference so I assumed to just leave that alone, since runtime wasn't an issue anyway. All my life I've only seen maps use insert with make_pair, even by my professors, so I don't know any other way to do it, I'm very confused on why a.at(i) is not working as an integer. Even setting an integer b to a.at(i) and putting it within make_pair, that was my issue.

Comment: Ahhh my bad, I'm not too familiar in maps maybe .second was the proper one to use. Anyhow I think .find is a better way to go, I haven't worked with sets in over two years so I forgot about that I'll look it up thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ints[a.at(i)]
```

Will insert `false` into the map if `a.at(i)` doesn't already exist.

```
ints.insert(make_pair((a.at(i)), true)
```

[Will fail to insert into the map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) if `a.at(i)` already exists. This means that you never set any elements of the map to `true`.

There are a few options to solve this.

`insert` returns a pair of an iterator and a bool indicating whether the insert was successful. You can use this to overwrite the existing value:

```
auto result = ints.insert(make_pair((a.at(i)), true);
if (!result.second)
{
  *result.first = true;
}
```

It's simpler though to just use the `[]` operator in the first place:

```
ints[a.at(i)] = true;
```

Alternatively you can use the fact that `insert` never overwrites the element to do everything in a single step:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
  auto result = ints.insert({a[i], true});
  if (!result.second) return i;
}
```

As all you're ever storing in the map is `true` a set might be simpler:

```
std::set<int> ints;
for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
  auto result = ints.insert(a[i]);
  if (!result.second) return i;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I was having trouble with what everyone else said. I'm trying to study insert and am wondering since insert returns whether or not the insert was successful in result.second, if the a[i] is already there does insert return false, thus allowing us to return the i value in that case?

Comment: Yes, insert returns false if the key already exists